# List Comprehension with "if" is not returning the same output as when I make a For Loop when counting the number of unique letters in a word

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone explain to me why there is a difference in output when using nested loops vs nested list comprehension?

```
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
def unique_english_letters (word) :
  unique = []
  for i in word: 
    if i not in unique: 
      unique.append(i)
  return len(unique)
print(unique_english_letters("mississippi"))
# outputs 4 (my expected output)
```

```
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
def unique_english_letters (word) :
  unique = []
  unique = [i for i in word if i not in unique]
  return len(unique)
print(unique_english_letters("mississippi"))
#outputs 11 (length of mississippi"
```

^ Output

Comment: In list comprehension you aren't perform unique.append, so it always True for any char

Comment: I don't think it can be done in a elegant way with a list comprehension, also why not just use `set` which eliminate all duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, this:

```
unique = []
unique = [i for i in word if i not in unique]
```

is equivalent to:

```
unique = [i for i in word if i not in []]
```

`unique` is an empty list while the list comprehension is evaluated, and then `unique` is re-assigned the results.

To do what you want in simple terms, use a `set` which can only contain unique values, and use set intersection(`&` operator) to generate the set of letters contained in `word`:

```
letters = set("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

def unique_english_letters(word):
    return len(letters & set(word))

print(unique_english_letters("mississippi"))
# output: 4
```